# How best to debug a crash within objc_msgSend?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, debugging, crash

I have a crash taking place when an `NSAutoreleasePool` drains. Presumably the pool is trying to deallocate an object that has been prematurely released by another piece of code. The crash I have is in the midst of `objc_msgSend` as it is trying to send a message to an object that doesn't exist anymore.

Given the stack state, what tips/tricks/processes/`gdb` commands do I have at my disposal to get information about the object in question and/or the point at which the illegitimate deallocation took place?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you have a hunch that it is a premature deletion, enable zombies to confirm your hypothesis and then debug what is going on. When you enable zombies, objects are not really destroyed, but set to a zombie state, which helps you to detect when they are accessed after they dealloc is called. Read more from [NSZombieEnabled](https://gist.github.com/JeOam/e62c95a0b4c21974bcf6)

Comment: Additionally, you can use Instruments' Object Alloc instrument to track the retain/release events of the object that was prematurely released.  It isn't the autorelease pool's -release that is the problem, but some prior -release, typically.

Answer (score 7):

The definitive article on this kind of crash: http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2008/09/22/objc_explain_So_you_crashed_in_objc_msgSend.html

Answer (score 4):

If you use NSZombieEnabled you can at least figure out what class the object is.

Comment: While correct, tequilatango's answer provides the answer along with some useful details.

Comment: Quite true. I could have at least provided a link to external information.

Answer (score 4):

I came across what appeared to be a crash in `objc_msgSend`. What was even stranger was `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` was not even getting reached before the so called crash occured!

In my case the crash turned out to be a breakpoint that I had inadvertantly set on a memory address that was getting called before any of my code was even reached.

[image]

After the hour or so of trying to figure this out, I unchecked the breakpoint, ran the code, face palmed and then continued my day pretending it had never happened…